# How visual studio C++ console get back when I closing the Qt GUI

Tags: qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio C++ application that call a Qt GUI application which running on Windows
my problem:

How I get back to the visual studio C++ console when the Qt GUI close

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <wincon.h>
#include <cstdlib>

BOOL InvokeConsole()
{
  BOOL status = AllocConsole();
  if (status)
  {
     freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
     freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
  }
  return status;
}
```

Call the function after destroying Qt GUI.